# Get all paths at multiple file select

Tags: jquery, html, fileapi

I use

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="upload" id="id_upload" />
```

and i can only get the value from one file

```
 value: "C:\fakepath\2012-09-18 10.47.18.jpg"
```

beacause path is not available from input.files

```
 files: FileList
  0: File
   lastModifiedDate: Tue Sep 18 2012 02:47:18 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))
    name: "2012-09-18 10.47.18.jpg"
    queueItem: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
    size: 1064960
    type: "image/jpeg"
    uploading: true
    webkitRelativePath: ""
    __proto__: File
```

How can i get the path for all selected files? What i try to get is EXIF data from alle selected files, using this [This EXIF reader](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exif/)

Comment: You are not _supposed_ to be able to read the local file path, for security reasons. You could try and see if your EXIF reader works with Image objects that have the image data set as a Data URI (and if so, create one via FileReader and assign it to an Image) – otherwise you will likely have to upload the files to a server first, if your EXIF reader only wants to work on images via HTTP URL(?).

Answer (score 2):

You can use following;

```
<input id="files" type="file" multiple/>
<div id="result"></div>

var filesInput = $("#files");

filesInput.on("change", function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files; //FileList object
    var result = $("#result");

    $.each(files, function(i, file) {
        var pReader = new FileReader(); 

        pReader.addEventListener("load", function(e){
            var pic = e.target;                
            result.append("<img class='thumbnail' src='" + pic.result + "'/>"); 
            show();

        });
        pReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    });


});
```

You can see demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/yT3PX/14** . When you selected files, You can click imgs to see exif data. However, it is not allowed to get exif data on jsfiddle. You can see multiple images loaded on demo

Comment: @AlizainPrasla thanks for your warning. Mozilla was having some issue about my code. I have updated code and the demo. You can see now [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yT3PX/14)